# Append html with line breaks is eavyier than appending html with no whitespaces?

Tags: html, jquery

I was asking myself which syntax is lighter or is there no differences between :

```
const html = '
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
</div>
'

$('#global_container').append(html)
```

and this :

```
const html = 
'<div class="container">'
    + '<div>'
        + '<input type="text" placeholder="login" />'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div>'
        + '<input type="password" placeholder="password" />'
    + '</div>'
+ '</div>'

$('#global_container').append(html)
```

In my project, I need to add a huge amount of html if the user press de modify button. That's why I was wondering how do I need to write my html code in my js file.

Comment: 1) don't write HTML in js, use a `<template>` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template))  or just `.show()` existing HTML that's `style='display:none'` - much easier 2)  it gets parsed and the whitepace removed, so don't worry about it unless you have millions of lines and are worried about transmission speed (in which case use server options to auto compress the file or provide a .min version)  **edit** 3) if you must take this route, use template-literals (example in the provided answer)

Comment: Go for maintainability above storage.  If your auto-format your second in any IDE (including SO snippet editor) it will remove the nested spaces making it harder to re-edit.

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be to use template-literals, because this gives various options. You can easily use dynamic data if required in future (data coming from APIs etc).

```
const html = `
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
    </div>
</div>
`;
```

Check [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

Coming to your question, I believe the first option would be better, since we don't have to go with different `concatenation processes` which obviously is a time-complex task.

Comment: hmmm ! Oh I see ! In JQuery Yup, we can use! I didn't noticed. Updating the answer mate. Thanks a lot for correcting me. :)

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m for encouragement  :) Means a lot